# Remove values from registry on uninstall using InstallShield installer

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, installshield

Is it possible to remove a string key value from the registry on uninstall using InstallShield installer. As much as I have searched, I wasn't able to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a little late, but I think you'll want to add a row to the Registry table (you can find this under the *Direct Editor* view in InstallShield). This will allow you to specify registries which will be deleted during the *RemoveRegistryValues* action.

For more information about this table, you can look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371168(v=vs.85).aspx

Alternatively, you could write a custom action to run on uninstall and use InstallScript to delete it. You can find an example of this here:

http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield18helplib/mergedProjects/installshield18langref/LangrefRegDBDeleteKey_example.htm

Hope this helps!

Andy